# .NETCore alternative for AppDomain.UnhandledException

Tags: exception, .net-core, unhandled-exception

According to http://www.michael-whelan.net/replacing-appdomain-in-dotnet-core/ some AppDomain functionality were replaced in .NETCore.
But I can't find the way to be notified about every unhandled exception occurred in my application. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to wait for .NET Core 1.2
... `AppDomain.UnhandledException` came back with [dotnet/corefx#11275](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/11275).